# Use a Java script with minor adaptations multiple times in an HTML document

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML file with a list of documents. Some of the filenames contain author, organization, knowledge area, and publication year information. In the following style: `"Document Title -a Author Name -j Publication Year.pdf"` I want the author name to be automatically colored blue, the publication year green, the knowledge area grey, and the organization purple.

The javascript from [adamoadamo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77106280) works, but I fail to insert it multiple times into the document so that all conceivable combinations of the information are colored correctly: text between **"-a"** and **"."**, **"-a"** and **"-"**, **"-j"** and **"."**, **"-s"** and **"-o"**, **"-s"** and **"-a"**, **"-s"** and **"-j"**, **"-s"** and **"."** and so on. Generally, only the variant of the Java script inserted at the bottom of the body area works. How can this be solved?

This was my try:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My files</title>
<style>
.filename { margin-left: 4em; } .author { color: blue; } .year { color: green; } .orga {color: purple} .science {color: grey} body {font-size: 1.2em}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<span class="filename">My document 1 -a Chris Drake -y 2021.pdf</span><br>
<span class="filename">My document 2 -a John Miller.txt</span><br>
<span class="filename">My document 3 -s Microbiology -a Peter Stone.html</span><br>
<span class="filename">My document 4 -o University of California -y 2017-08-31.mp4</span><br>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- Text between "-a" and "-" -->
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.filename').forEach((elem) => {
    const text = elem.textContent;
    const newHtml = text.replace(/-a (.*?)\-/, 
                                 '-a <span class="author">$1</span>-');
    elem.innerHTML = newHtml;
  });
};

<!-- Text between "-a" and "." -->
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.filename').forEach((elem) => {
    const text = elem.textContent;
    const newHtml = text.replace(/-a (.*?)\./, 
                                 '-a <span class="author">$1</span>.');
    elem.innerHTML = newHtml;
  });
};

<!-- Text between "-y" and "." -->
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.filename').forEach((elem) => {
    const text = elem.textContent;
    const newHtml = text.replace(/-y (.*?)\./, 
                                 '-y <span class="year">$1</span>.');
    elem.innerHTML = newHtml;
  });
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why add the same script 2 times? The second onload event will overwrite the first (a reason you should append event listener). Besides that, you run the script at the DOMContentLoaded event, there is no reason to reuse the script as they both run at the end.

Comment: Besides what's already been said by others, is the order of the flags (`-a`, `-o`, ...) fixed? If not, you're going to need to increase the complexity of your regular expression, or properly parse the content first.

Comment: Why don't you just use CSS classes?

Comment: @fatpenguin CSS doesn't regex text content

Comment: If he has an HTML document he surely could add CSS classes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you re-assign into same event call, that's why only last one works.

Join all your code into single function:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.filename').forEach((elem) => {
    let text = elem.textContent;
    text = text.replace(/-a (.*?)\-/, '-a <span class="author">$1</span>-');
    text = text.replace(/-([ay]) (.*?)\./, '-$1 <span class="author">$2</span>.');

    elem.innerHTML = text;
  });
};
```

Comment: either that or append events with `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { ... })`